# Difference between an int passed by reference and a passed address of an int

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, reference

```
void VoidRef (int &ref){
   ref++;
}

void VoidPtr (int *ptr){
  (*ptr)++;
}

int test= 5;

VoidRef(test);
cout << test;  // is 6

VoidPtr(&test);
cout << test;  // is 7 !
```

Why do both voids do the same thing?
Which void needs more resources?

Comment: Yes, they both do the same thing (though I'd go with the first one because it involves implementing a less intrusive syntax).

Comment: A references is usually implemented as pointer under the hood so resource wise they should be the same. References in general should be preferred.

Comment: The main advantage (IMO) of using a reference is it makes it impossible to accidentally pass a null or otherwise invalid pointer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between pointer variable and reference variable in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

Comment: They're called "functions", not "voids". The "void" in the function declaration means the function doesn't return anything. And yes, pointers and references are quite similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
void VoidRef (int &ref){
              //^^pass by reference
   ref++;
}

void VoidPtr (int *ptr){
                //^^ptr stores address of test
  (*ptr)++;
}
```

`Why do both voids do the same thing?`

`ref` is a reference to test, i.e., an alias of `test`, so operation on `ref` is also operated on `test`.

`ptr` is a pointer that stores the memory address of `test`, so `(*ptr)++` will increment the value that stored on the memory address by one. The reason that the first output is 6 and the second output is 7 since each call to those two functions increments the variable value by 1.

You can `think of` both `VoidRef` and `VoidPtr` operates on the address of the variable `test`, therefore, they have same effect.